# spring boot compilation fails

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

after a "maven clean" my spring boot project doesn't compile anymore

**RunAs --> Spring Boot App**

```
Impossible to find or load the main class com.in28minutes.springboot.rest.example.springboot2restservicebasic.SpringBoot2RestServiceBasicApplication
```

so from the terminal: **mvn spring-boot:run**    (or **spring-boot:repackage** )

```
Compilation failure
[ERROR] /D:/eclipse-workspace/spring-boot-2-rest-service-basic/spring-boot-2-rest-service-basic/src/main/java/com/in28minutes/springboot/rest/example/springboot2restservicebasic
/api/StudentResource.java:[18,45] package net.bytebuddy.implementation.bytecode does not exist
```

**pom.xml**

```
...
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
..
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you put the dependency below in your project's `pom.xml`?

````
```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
        <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.11</version>
    </dependency>
```
````

`version` can be another you want.

Comment: adding this dependecy the program works!  but why did it work before? i edited the post with my previous pom (that worked)

Comment: Sorry, the codes you submitted are so simple and few that I can't get the idea.